# Why do I keep getting this error in R when trying to produce a variogram?

Tags: r, time-series

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE) # importing the data
attach(data) # attaching the data
```

```
library(pastecs)
```

```
series <- ts(data, start = 1950, end = 1997, frequency = 1)
```

```
acf(series, plot = FALSE)
```

```
vario(series) # variogram
```

Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output

> Error in data.frame(distance = as.numeric(distance), semivario = val)
> : arguments imply differing number of rows: 4560, 9215

Comment: Please don't `attach` 'data'`   also, `ts` expects a vector as input whereas your `data` is a data.frame.  Do you have a single column, then use `ts(data[[1]], ..`

Comment: @akrun, I have two columns of data. How would that be formatted?

Comment: Depends on which column you want to make the time series, i.e. if it is first column `data[[1]]` or second `data[[2]]` or may use its column names.  As you have used `attach`, the column names will be objects in the global env, you can check `ls()` to find those objects and call directly

Comment: @akrun am I able to make them both part of the time series? The first column is the year, the second column is lbs. of cheese produced.

Comment: Then, you may need `ts(data[[2]], start = min(data[[1]]), end = max(data[[1]]), frequency = 1)`  It is better to provide a small reproducible example for others to help